# How to work with jQuery datatables plugins?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project which contains datatables so I want to work with datatables plugins from datables.net. I followed all the instructions but I didn't get a result (search input and entries label are not appearing).

I think that there is a problem on links or references.

Here is my code - please I need your help on this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>nchlh tekhdem</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mb-3 mt-3" >
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered mydatatable " style="width: 100%"  >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Detected in Version</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Prio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Detected in Version</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Prio</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.mydatatable').Datatable() ; 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly replace the js code as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { $('.mydatatable').DataTable();});
```

you are missing `document.ready` function.

`document.ready` function is executed once all the js files are loaded. Kindly note that, after all files are loaded then you can executes its functions.

Thanks, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is wrong, it should be

```
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('.mydatatable').Datatable() ; 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thins just fine, you make a mistake with data table Object name:

```
  $('.mydatatable').DataTable();
```

Not

```
  $('.mydatatable').Datatable() ;
```

Better used Id:

```
 <table id="mydatatable "  class="table table-striped table-bordered mydatatable " style="width: 100%"  >

<script>

    $(document).ready( function () {
     $('#mydatatable').DataTable();
   });

</script>
```